# Removing new lines

Tags: php, replace, break, lines

I have a function in a class:

```
public function displayComments($postorpage, $id_postorpage){
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".DB."`.`mmsv_servers_page_comments` WHERE `id_postorpage`='$id_postorpage'");
        while($comment = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
        $added = new Time;
        $elapsed = $added->displayElapsedSignificant($comment->data);
         echo "
            <h3>$comment->nick</h3> 
            <i>$elapsed</i>
            <p>".addSecurityView($comment->text)."</p>
            ";
        }       
    }
```

And the function addSecurityView which supposes to remove the break lines doesn't work:

```
function addSecurityView($value)
{

    $result = preg_replace(array("/\r\n\r\n/", "/\n\n/"), array("\r\n", "\n"), $value);

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Your code works for me.

Comment: You say _supposes to remove the break lines_. It doesn't remove all line breaks, only when there are two line breaks in a row, it turns them into one. Why do you need to do this, extra line breaks make no difference in HTML (except in `<pre>` blocks).

Comment: If you want to nuke from orbit newlines try `$new = preg_replace('#\r|\n#', '', $data);`

Answer (score 1):

i believe this should work with you as it works with me

```
<?php
$trans = array("\r" => "" , "\n" => "");
echo strtr("\n hi and \r hi", $trans);
?>
```

and consider on changing from MySql to MySqli or PDO

Comment: @MuchaZ it will more easy for me if you show me exactly what you want it to be and what happens when you try this code . not just it dosent work

Comment: I think you may try using `\r` and `\n` instead.

Comment: @HamZa even though it works , its the same things nothing will change

Comment: @AlmoullimDev. No it's not the same. Try `echo "a/r/nb";` and `echo "a\r\nb";`. Check the difference

Comment: @HamZa oh , im sorry i thought you meant the instead of \n and \r use \r and \n , i didn't focus on the (/ , \ )

Answer (score 0):

Try using strtr function, with replace pairs.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php

Comment: Both your code and strtr work for me. 
"which supposes to remove the break lines" - maybe it's because of this. Your code doesn't remove break lines, it replaces 2 breaks with 1.

Answer (score 0):

try this one here

```
$string = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string));
```

here is nice simple SECURE output function

```
function secureOutput($string) {

    $string = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string)); //this will remove multiple whitespaces

    return htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES);
}
```

Comment: @MuchaZ: instead of just saying that it doesn't work, you could also tell what output you expect for a specific input. (And then of course mention both input and expected output.)

Comment: I got a field in DB: "Some comment.\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n" and I want to display that without "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n".

Comment: that regex will remove all multiple white spaces including new lines, are you sure you have new lines in your db and not literal \n ?

Comment: I don't need them in the DB, but I can't exclude them in the `function:function addSecurity($value)
{
    $tochange = addslashes(htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($value)));
    $return = str_replace(array(
        "'",
        ";",
        "`",
        "*",
        "\r",
        "\n"), "", $tochange);
        
    return $return;
}`

Comment: why are you using real_escape_string on an output ? also addslashes ? can you tell what output you are getting now ? like what a user would see

Comment: The output of this function goes to the DB.

Comment: it's because you addslashes... remove that function also all you need for inserting them in your db in real_escape_string remove the rest and use that secureOutput() that i posted when you want to output something